# Sails.js socket put with form data

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

I have a standard form. I want to use this to put the data.

```
io.socket.put('/user/3', data, function (data, jwres){
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(jwres));
        });
```

Is there a clean and sensible way to pass all the form input values into "data" without constructing the JSON manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this module using jQuery

`$('#my-form').serializeObject();`

https://github.com/hongymagic/jQuery.serializeObject

You can also implement your own function which does the same, this link will show you how to do this.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/serializeobject